# Fragment getActivity is always returning null from Async Task

Tags: android, android-asynctask, facebook-android-sdk

I have called an `AsyncTask` inside my `fragment`. I was calling `getActivity()` from within `doInBackground` of that `AsyncTask`, but `getActivity` is returning `null`.

If I call `getActivity` outside from `AsyncTask` its working properly, but I need instance of `activity` inside my `asyncTask` itself.

Any help would be appreciated.. !!!

Comment: post code here..

Comment: Pass the Fragment in constructor of that asynTaks and create weekReference of Fragment inside you Aysn. Then getActivity from it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Pass Activity to AsyncTask method**

```
new Demo().execute(getActivity());

public class Demo extends AsyncTask<Activity,Void,Void>{
    Activity activity=null;
    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Activity... params) {
        activity=params[0]; //get the activity instance 
        //Do your task

        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes Thank you for the help.. This would surely work but I had used context from onAttach as I was already having context from it :)

Answer (score 2):

Both Solution will work that i am posting. Try any of them.

**Solution 1 :**

Try to call your `AsynTask` in `onActivityCreated` rather then in `onCreateView`as sometimes it happens Activity instance return to be `null` in `onCreateView`.

```
@Override
public void onActivityCreated(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
 // call AsynTask here, getActivity() not return null here
}
```

**Solution 2 :**

Get `activity` instance when `fragment` is attached on `Activity` and then use `Activity` `context` in your `AsynTask`(No need to call getActivity()).

```
private Activity mContext;

// called for API equal or above 23
@Override
public void onAttach(Context context) {
    super.onAttach(context);
    this.mContext = (Activity) context;
}

/*
* Deprecated on API 23
*/
@Override
public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
    super.onAttach(activity);
    this.mContext = activity;
}

// Use mContext in asyntask
```

Comment: Thanks.. First approach does not applies in my case as I have to call async task based on a event and not from lifecycle methods. I have fixed it using second approach. By using latest support library I do not have to include context using the deprecated onAttach(Activity activity) method.. Got Context from First  method onAttach(Context context) itself even for devices with API level below 23

Answer (score 1):

In your fragment add

```
Activity mActivity; //declare as global variable

@Override
public void onAttach(Context context) {
super.onAttach(context);
  if (context instanceof Activity){
    mActivity=(Activity) context;
}
}
```

then use `mActivity` instead of `getActivity()` in your `AsyncTask`.

Comment: Yes this would definitely work.. Although this method has been deprecated.. The newly available method in sdk is :
   @Override
    public void onAttach(Context context) {
        super.onAttach(context);
        mContext = context;
    }

Answer (score -1):

It may be possible that async task is going on but fragment closed so u have pass getActivty() to AsyncTask.

Comment: No this is not the case in my case.